# moving a row next to another row in panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

I am trying to format a data frame from 2 rows to 1 rows. but I am encountering some issues. Do you have any idea on how to do that? Here the code and df:

[image: this is the starting df]

[image: This is the code and resulting df. as you can see I have NaN. I want to reduce everything to one row]

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!  please review the guidelines when posting questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to convert two rows into one, you can do the following...

1. Stack the dataframe and reset the index at level=1, which will convert the data and columns into a stack. This will end up having each of the column headers as a column (called level_1) and the data as another column(called 0)
2. Then set the index as level_1, which will move the column names as index
3. Remove the index name (level_1). Then transpose the dataframe

Code is shown below.

```
df3=df3.stack().reset_index(level=1).set_index('level_1')
df3.index.name = None
df3=df3.T
```

**Output**
df3

[image]